# I have installed Another WordPress Classifieds plugin I have to integrate with woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed Another WordPress Classifieds plugin.

I have to integrate with woocommerce plugin. How I can do?

Comment: I can't understand the question

Comment: How I can see payments of Another WordPress Classifieds plugin in woo-commerce order table.

Comment: You need customize the code for Classifieds Plugin to use with Woo Commerce. Please look at this [link](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/woocommerce-integration-for-classifieds-plugin)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have developed one extension for that, Now everything is working well.